# Plot Kaplan-Meier for Cox regression

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I have a Cox proportional hazards model set up using the following code in R that predicts mortality. Covariates A, B and C are added simply to avoid confounding (i.e. age, sex, race) but we are really interested in the predictor X. X is a continuous variable.

```
cox.model <- coxph(Surv(time, dead) ~ A + B + C + X, data = df)
```

Now, I'm having troubles plotting a Kaplan-Meier curve for this. I've been searching on how to create this figure but I haven't had much luck. I'm not sure if plotting a Kaplan-Meier for a Cox model is possible? Does the Kaplan-Meier adjust for my covariates or does it not need them?

What I did try is below, but I've been told this isn't right.

```
plot(survfit(cox.model), xlab = 'Time (years)', ylab = 'Survival Probabilities')
```

I also tried to plot a figure that shows cumulative hazard of mortality. I don't know if I'm doing it right since I've tried it a few different ways and get different results. Ideally, I would like to plot two lines, one that shows the risk of mortality for the 75th percentile of X and one that shows the 25th percentile of X. How can I do this?

I could list everything else I've tried, but I don't want to confuse anyone!

Many thanks.

Comment: It's not that the "KM curves adjust for covariates" but rather that one can construct predicted step-function survival curves from model fits. Most people would use the term KM curve to refer to unadjusted survival curves. You also need to specify all the variables to make a prediction. See the coded example below.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example taken from [this paper](http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendix/Appendix-Cox-Regression.pdf).

```
url <- "http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/data/Rossi.txt"
Rossi <- read.table(url, header=TRUE)
Rossi[1:5, 1:10]

#   week arrest fin age  race wexp         mar paro prio educ
# 1   20      1  no  27 black   no not married  yes    3    3
# 2   17      1  no  18 black   no not married  yes    8    4
# 3   25      1  no  19 other  yes not married  yes   13    3
# 4   52      0 yes  23 black  yes     married  yes    1    5
# 5   52      0  no  19 other  yes not married  yes    3    3

mod.allison <- coxph(Surv(week, arrest) ~ 
                        fin + age + race + wexp + mar + paro + prio,
                        data=Rossi)
mod.allison

# Call:
# coxph(formula = Surv(week, arrest) ~ fin + age + race + wexp + 
#    mar + paro + prio, data = Rossi)
#
#
#                   coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z      p
# finyes         -0.3794     0.684   0.1914 -1.983 0.0470
# age            -0.0574     0.944   0.0220 -2.611 0.0090
# raceother      -0.3139     0.731   0.3080 -1.019 0.3100 
# wexpyes        -0.1498     0.861   0.2122 -0.706 0.4800
# marnot married  0.4337     1.543   0.3819  1.136 0.2600
# paroyes        -0.0849     0.919   0.1958 -0.434 0.6600
# prio            0.0915     1.096   0.0286  3.194 0.0014
#
# Likelihood ratio test=33.3  on 7 df, p=2.36e-05  n= 432, number of events= 114
```

Note that the model uses `fin, age, race, wexp, mar, paro, prio` to predict `arrest`. As mentioned in [this document](http://anson.ucdavis.edu/~hiwang/teaching/10fall/R_tutorial%201.pdf) the `survfit()` function uses the Kaplan-Meier estimate for the survival rate.

```
plot(survfit(mod.allison), ylim=c(0.7, 1), xlab="Weeks",
     ylab="Proportion Not Rearrested")
```

[image: survival estimate plot]

We get a plot (with a 95% confidence interval) for the survival rate. For the cumulative hazard rate you can do

```
# plot(survfit(mod.allison)$cumhaz)
```

but this doesn't give confidence intervals. However, no worries! We know that H(t) = -ln(S(t)) and we have confidence intervals for S(t). All we need to do is

```
sfit <- survfit(mod.allison)
cumhaz.upper <- -log(sfit$upper)
cumhaz.lower <- -log(sfit$lower)
cumhaz <- sfit$cumhaz # same as -log(sfit$surv)
```

Then just plot these

```
plot(cumhaz, xlab="weeks ahead", ylab="cumulative hazard",
     ylim=c(min(cumhaz.lower), max(cumhaz.upper)))
lines(cumhaz.lower)
lines(cumhaz.upper)
```

[image: cumhaz]

You'll want to use `survfit(..., conf.int=0.50)` to get bands for 75% and 25% instead of 97.5% and 2.5%.

Comment: I'm not sure that setting the conf.int = 0.50 is the same as plotting survival curve estimates for the 25th and 75th percentile of X values. I thought I would have had to use survfit.coxph function for the Kaplan-Meier curve, not sure about cumulative hazard though.

Comment: Mostly helpful but the last sentence is just wrong, and since that was the thrust of the question really needs to be fixed!

Comment: @Hims regarding your comment about ``survfit.coxph`` - based on the way that ``R`` deals with class objects, ``survfit.coxph`` is being called when I call ``survfit``

Comment: I'm not sure if its possible - the ``survfit`` function estimates the survival function and derives the ``cumhaz`` prediction using this survival function (done with the Kaplan-Meier method). So we can't get separate the ``cumhaz`` prediction into separate hazards.

Answer (score 4):

The request for estimated survival curve at the 25th and 75th percentiles for X first requires determining those percentiles and specifying values for all the other covariates in a dataframe to be used as newdata argument to survfit.:

Can use the data suggested by other resondent from Fox's website, although on my machine it required building an `url`-object:

```
 url <- url("http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/data/Rossi.txt")
 Rossi <- read.table(url, header=TRUE)
```

It's probably not the best example for this wquestion but it does have a numeric variable that we can calculate the quartiles:

```
> summary(Rossi$prio)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   1.000   2.000   2.984   4.000  18.000
```

So this would be the model fit and survfit calls:

```
 mod.allison <- coxph(Surv(week, arrest) ~ 
                         fin + age + race + prio ,
                         data=Rossi)
 prio.fit <- survfit(mod.allison, 
                     newdata= data.frame(fin="yes", age=30, race="black", prio=c(1,4) ))
 plot(prio.fit, col=c("red","blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to do a log-rank test between the red and blue curve?

Comment: You could get a log-rank test of the significance of the `prio` variable in the `mod.allison` model under the conditions of the data on which it was built and estimated. Is that what you want?

Comment: I think so. If I do summary() of the model it returns a single logrank result for all the coeffients. I want to test between the 2 prio quartiles instead.

Comment: I don’t think there is a method to do a statistical test as you describe it.

Comment: Looking at this again I think what would suffice would be to compare the two models with and without the prio covariate and take the difference in deviance and compare to Chi-square statistic with one degree of freedom. It is a log-likelihood test.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the values of the confounders to a fixed value and plotting the predicted survival probabilities at multiple points in time for given values of X (as @IRTFM suggested in his answer), results in a *conditional* effect estimate. That is not what a standard Kaplan-Meier estimator is used for and I don't think that is what the original poster wanted. Usually we are interested in *average causal effects*. In other words: What would the survival probability be if X had been set to some specific value x in the entire sample?

We can obtain this probability using the cox-model that was fit plus g-computation. In g-computation, we set the value of X to x in the entire sample and then use the cox model to predict the survival probability at t for each individual, using their observed covariate values in the process. Then we simply take the average of those predictions to obtain our final estimate. By repeating this process for a range of points in time and a range of possible values for X, we obtain a three-dimensional survival surface. We can then visualize this surface using color scales.

This can be done using the `contsurvplot` R-package I developed, as discussed in this previous answer: [Converting survival analysis by a continuous variable to categorical](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/496329/converting-survival-analysis-by-a-continuous-variable-to-categorical-so-as-to-fi) or in the documentation of the package. More information about this strategy in general can be found in the preprint version of my article on this topic: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.04644.pdf